# Google stackdriver database agent for OracleDB?

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

We know that Google's stackdriver supports monitroing for third-party applications like `postgresql`, `mysql`, `couchdb` and others mentioned here. They have also defined the service configuration files for the monitoring agent here.

As per my understanding, I think they somehow use `collectd's` third-party plugins somewhere in this. Also, since there exists a plugin for `Oracle`, stackdriver should support that too. But I can't see `Oracle` in the list of supported third-party applications. So, does stackdriver support it or not?

Comment: Since this don't involve programming I flagged, you might want to move into the right blog.

Comment: See the explanation and example in the link. You would deliver your metrics using custom metrics. Be aware of the cost implications of this mechanism. If you want to get the Oracle plugin supported by Stackdriver, you should submit an issue.https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/custom-metrics-agent https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187228&template=1162638

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stackdriver monitoring agent package does not bundle the `oracle` plugin, so it's not supported. You may be able to write a shell script (invoked via the `exec` plugin) or a Python script (invoked via the `python` plugin) to query your database, and the [custom metrics mechanism](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/custom-metrics-agent) to ingest metrics.
You could also try [BindPlane](https://bluemedora.com/solutions/by-integration/?_sft_product_support=bindplane-for-stackdriver&_sf_s=oracle) from our partner, Blue Medora.

*Disclaimer: I'm an engineer on the Stackdriver team.*